# Are there solutions to block pornography on iOS and watchOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation

I need an effective solution for preventing my ability to see porn and immodest content on both my iPhone 11 Pro Max and iWatch 5 cellular.

Once that is accomplished:

- I do want to otherwise  retain maximum functionality on these devices.
- Also this solution needs to have Some measure of uninstall protection

What software or service can help with this content blocking?

Comment: Since this is a worldwide sire, who do you trust to define pornography? I tried to edit this to start to adhere to our software recommendation guidelines, but it might also need the items required for an off site recommendation question - namely editing this to show your research and document why the solution you found isn’t good enough.

Comment: How is this pornography appearing?  Just randomly?  AirDropped?  Email?  Text or iMessage?  Your browser?  Also, *where* is it happening?  Home, work, everywhere you go?  Also, to punctuate what @bmike said.. pornography is one thing, but “immodest content” is such a broad and subjective term.  How do *you* define it?

Answer (score 3):

On iOS there is a setting for "Content and Privacy Restrictions Go to Settings -> Screen Time ->  Content & Privacy Restrictions.  Under this setting, there are many types of content restrictions which you can apply.

Many browsers also have content restrictions.